# Alert in Jquery pagination

Tags: jquery

how to create an event in jquery that will trigger in the pagination if it is the last page.
here is my code

```
$(function () {
    $('#myTable').jPaginate({
        'max': 40,
        'page': 1,
        'links': 'buttons'
    });
});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.jPaginate = function (m) {
        var n = {
            'max': 50,
            'page': 100,
            'links': 'text'
        };
        var o = $.extend(n, m);
        o.max = Math.max(1, o.max);
        o.page = Math.max(1, o.page);
        return this.each(function () {
            var c = $(this);
            if (c.is('table')) {
                var d = c.find('tbody');
                if (d.length == 0) {
                    d = c
                }
                var f = 0;
                var g = 0;
                d.find('tr').each(function (i) {
                    var a = $(this);
                    if (i % o.max == 0) {
                        f++
                    }
                    a.addClass('jPaginate-row-' + f);
                    if (f != o.page) {
                        a.hide()
                    }
                    if (i == 0) {
                        a.find('td,th').each(function () {
                            g += $(this).attr('colspan') != undefined ? 1 + parseInt($(this).attr('colspan'), 10) : 1
                        })
                    }
                });
                var h = c.find('tfoot');
                if (h.length == 0) {
                    h = $('<tfoot></tfoot>');
                    h.appendTo(c)
                }
                var j = $('<th colspan="' + g + '"></th>');
                $('<tr class="jPaginate-links-row"></tr>').append(j).appendTo(h);
                if (f > 1) {
                    function showPage(a) {
                        d.find('tr').hide();
                        d.find('.jPaginate-row-' + a).css('display', 'table-row')
                    }
                    var k = '';
                    switch (o.links) {
                    case 'select':
                        for (var i = 1; i <= f; i++) {
                            k += '<option value="' + i + '"' + 'class="jPaginate-link-option' + (i == o.page ? ' jPaginate-link-option-selected" selected="selected' : '') + '">' + i + '</option>'
                        }
                        j.html('<select class="jPaginate-link-select">' + k + '</select>');
                        j.find('select').change(function () {
                            var a = $(this);
                            a.find('.jPaginate-link-option').removeClass('jPaginate-link-option-selected');
                            a.find('.jPaginate-link-option[value=' + a.val() + ']').addClass('jPaginate-link-option-selected');
                            showPage(a.val())
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'buttons':
                        j.html('<input class="jPaginate-link-button-first" type="button" value="&laquo;">' + '<input class="jPaginate-link-button-previous" type="button" value="&lt;">' + '<input class="jPaginate-link-input" type="text" value="' + o.page + '">' + '<input class="jPaginate-link-button-next" type="button" value="&gt;">' + '<input class="jPaginate-link-button-last" type="button" value="&raquo;">');
                        var l = j.find('.jPaginate-link-input');
                        l.change(function () {
                            var a = $(this);
                            var b = isNaN(a.val()) ? 1 : a.val();
                            a.val(Math.max(1, Math.min(f, b)));
                            showPage(a.val())
                        });
                        j.find('.jPaginate-link-button-first').click(function () {
                            l.val(1).change()
                        });
                        j.find('.jPaginate-link-button-last').click(function () {
                            l.val(f).change();
                            $('#r').html('<?=$total?>');
                        });
                        j.find('.jPaginate-link-button-previous').click(function () {
                            l.val(parseInt(l.val(), 10) - 1).change()
                        });
                        j.find('.jPaginate-link-button-next').click(function () {
                            l.val(parseInt(l.val(), 10) + 1).change()
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        for (var i = 1; i <= f; i++) {
                            k += '<a class="jPaginate-link-text' + (i == o.page ? ' jPaginate-link-text-active' : '') + '" href="#">' + i + '</a> '
                        }
                        j.html(k);
                        $('.jPaginate-link-text').click(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            j.find('a').removeClass('jPaginate-link-text-active');
                            $(this).addClass('jPaginate-link-text-active');
                            showPage($(this).text())
                        });
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: last page shown? or trying to go to next page when on last page?

Comment: when you are already in the last page. for example the pages are 4, you are in the page3 when you try to click the last page, it will appear. alert that you are in the last page..